# Lighter version of sans serif typeface

Tags: fonts, pdftex, bold

I am using the Frutiger font as the sans serif font in my document. It is invoked by

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{pfr}
```

However this font is too bold for my taste. There is a ligher version available. I would like `{\sf Test}` to be rendered as

```
{\fontfamily{pfr}\fontseries{l}\selectfont Test}
```

and `{\sf \textbf{Test}}` to be rendered as

```
{\fontfamily{pfr}\fontseries{m}\selectfont Test}
```

(that is, the normal variant is now used as the bold typeface). How do I achieve this? I don't know the proper commands to so this and I suspect my `\renewcommand` is not the correct way of switching to Frutiger in the first place.

Comment: Adding a command `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}` also affects my serif font.

Comment: You didn't mention which package you use for the font support. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that can be experimented with?

Comment: I cannot add a minimal working example because I ama using non-fee typefaces. I am not using a package, just the command I mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remark: don't use `\sf` command, better keep with `\sffamily`. The following works only with this one. Putting the following by the end of your preamble should work, it surely does for *some* font that provides both `l` and `m` series:

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname sffamily \endcsname{\def\bfdefault{m}}
\makeatother
```

The command `\g@addto@macro` re-defines the macro `\sffamily` to locally re-define `bf` series to `m`. Usage of `\csname` is necessary since `\sffamily` is a protected command and the command itself ends with an extra space. The `\makeat...` commands makes the commands with `@` in name accessible. (Thanks to *egreg* for explanations and corrections.)

Comment: may I ask why did you delete your answer to [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94583/14497)? Your answer works perfectly! (I'm just experimenting with egreg's answer, too.)

Comment: @NunoNunes that answer is malacious, try `\sffamily this \rmfamily that`. The egreg's one should work better.