# Redefine \textbf to always be sans serif

Tags: bold, sans-serif

As the title says, is there any way to make bold text automatically also be typeset in sans serif? I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{???}
```

I don't know what to redefine to though?

Comment: This question is somewhat a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94583/changing-the-default-series-of-the-sans-serif-family-only just with family and series exchanged. However, the **egreg**'s solution seems to be quite complicated to tweak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried inserting

```
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{{\bfseries\sffamily#1}}
```

in the preamble of your document? Note the double pair of curly braces; the innner pair serves to constrain the application of `\bfseries\sffamily` to the argument of `\textbf`.

*Addendum*: As the comments by cgnieder and egreg allude to, the LaTeX kernel (see the file `latex.ltx`, ca. line 3720) provides the following definition of `\textbf`:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}
```

The macro `\DeclareTextFontCommand` takes care to keep things tidy if, say, `\textbf` is encountered while TeX is in math mode. To keep things equally tidy, then, it's preferable to redefine `\textbf` as follows:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries\sffamily}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries\sffamily}`

Comment: @cgnieder I would too. This definition is really poor.

Comment: @tohecz - Fixed the double brace issue. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but this is one of the rare cases in which I feel the urge of downvoting. I'll try to resist.

Comment: @egreg - I've provided an addendum that highlights the virtue of going the `DeclareTextFontCommand` route.

Comment: @Mico It's wrong anyway. The command to be redefined is `\bfseries`, not `\textbf`.

Comment: @egreg - The OP asked how to redefine `\textbf`. He/she may  want to be able to continue to use `\bfseries` on its own, e.g., for typesetting something in bold *without* switching to sans-serif. Similarly, he/she may not want to modify the meaning of `\mathbf` just because `\textbf` gets modified.

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `\bfseries` in `latex.ltx` reads

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\bfseries
        {\not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbf
         \fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont}
```

so it's sufficient to say

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bfseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbfsf
  \fontfamily\sfdefault\fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont
}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\makeatother
```

Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % for sans serif bold slanted

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bfseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\bfseries\mathbfsf
  \fontfamily\sfdefault\fontseries\bfdefault\selectfont
}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{n}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This {\bfseries is sans} and this \textbf{too}; what
about math? Here it is: $a\textbf{x}$; also italic is
applied: \textbf{\textit{abc}} or \textit{\textbf{abc}}.

\end{document}
```

Of course if serif math bold is wanted, `\mathbfsf` should remain `\mathbf` and the font alphabet declaration should be removed.

[image]